# Secure a single page in an ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, security

I often have a need to secure a single page (i.e. Reports) on a public facing app so that only authorized users may access the page. In the past, this mean setting up a custom login form or using the ASP.NET membership provider or something else far too complex to serve the purpose. Is there an easier (safe) way to secure a single page in this fashion?

Some things I've considered:

- Client certificates (initial setup is a pain)
- A single master password (works in a pinch, but feels dirty)
- Restrict access by host address (cumbersome when the need arises to allow external users access to the page). Also, need to support access via proxy (X-Forwarded-For) which can be faked by technical users)

Are there other options? Recommendations?

Comment: Do you have access to Active Directory?

Comment: For the most part, no. Our applications are hosted in the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in your web.config file something like what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701136/how-to-secure-a-single-aspx-page-in-asp-net-website). As far as authentication is concerned the easiest way is to use windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

A login system is your best option.  If you don't want to go through the trouble of setting up and managing a login system yourself, consider using OpenAuth.

You can achieve functionality pretty easily using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).  Users can then log in with their Google, Yahoo, StackOverflow, etc. accounts, and you get a token that you can store to limit access with.